# set Portrait Mode to Landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I tried using a Category....
Add new files and select Category and make subclass UINavigationController class.

here is the code for category for .h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @interface UINavigationController (orientation)

    @end

code for .m file

#import "UINavigationController+orientation.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (orientation)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    if (delegate.islandscape)
    {
        // for iPhone, you could also return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
@end
```

isLandscape is declared in App delegate to check weather First view controller or secondView Controller isLandscape is Bool.

Now FirstViewController.m file i want that in Portarit mode so used this code

```
- (IBAction)PlayClicked:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    delegate.islandscape=YES;

    ViewController * v=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:v animated:NO completion:nil];


    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:YES];

}


- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

and SecondViewController i want that in Landscape mode used this one.

```
delegate.islandscape=NO;   // called transfer to Category 

- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

I refer this [1st ViewController in Protrait and SecondViewController in Landscape Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485445/1st-viewcontroller-in-protrait-and-secondviewcontroller-in-landscape-mode) and this [Landscape Apps Xcode 5 / iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857964/landscape-apps-xcode-5-ios-7?rq=1) and other but not working for me

Comment: I know this is not xcode issue... but This is works on ios6 and ios5 but not working in ios7....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this project on github
https://github.com/alloy/ForceOrientationTest

[image]

Comment: its not woking in my app but i add my project in this Demo and it woking fine

Comment: i faced same issue, i resolved it by presenting viewcontroller rather than navigation controller

Comment: hi, but there is one problem when i push the view in landscape then rotate the simulator or device then back to portrait view then the view is portrait but device and simulator are in landscape see image

Comment: see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651657/rotate-portrait-to-landscape-in-pdfreader-in-ios6-and-ios7