# Rotate Portrait to Landscape in pdfreader in ios6 and ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rotation, ios7

I am developing an application that read pdf in landscape mode. I write the following code and its works fine. But my problem is I download pdf reder code from 
https://github.com/brow/leaves and implement that code in my application, after that in project my `LandScapeViewController`'s base class is `LeavesViewController` (if I use the baseclass is `UIViewController` then it is working fine). So  when i push from viewController to  `LandScapeViewController` it works properly. But at that time i rotate the view more then two times  or in 360 degree then i go to back. Its not working properly. Means after landscapeviewcontroller it must transfer portraitView but it can't do this. I give my project. Please Help me.

I search lots of in SO but all solution is base class is `UIViewController` but i need the `LeavesViewController`

Before rotation My first view is

[image]

then click on Button and rotate the view in 360 degree, After rotation click on back button and it display view like

[image]

This is the my code == [MyCode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8rcn39ghz8oj0u/PortraitLandScape.zip)

I write that code from heare [set Portrait Mode to Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225255/set-portrait-mode-to-landscape)

Comment: Are you using auto layout? I am at work, and can't access the project.

Comment: @LeoNatan NO, I am not using auto layout..

Comment: http://www.disalvotech.com/blog/app-development/iphone/ios-6-rotation-solution/  see this link